# Get directories beginning with P in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to get all directories starting with "P".

In cmd you would do this:

```
dir p*
```

**How do you do it in Windows PowerShell?**

I tried this but it returns nothing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\thePath\* -dir -Include p*
```

Removing the `-Include p*` would return all folders as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either include the pattern directly in the `-Path` argument:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\thePath\p* -Directory
```

... or use the `-Filter` argument, which is the faster alternative, because it filters at the source:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\thePath -Filter p* -Directory
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters are notoriously counterintuitive in that they only operate on the input path or pattern itself, not on the *child* items of a given input path - except if `-Recurse` is also specified.

In your case, given that your `-Path` argument ends in `*`, the `-Include` filter *should* work, but inexplicably doesn't due to the additional presence of the `-Directory` switch - this should be considered a bug.
Seemingly, with `Get-ChildItem` - as opposed to `Get-Item` - `-Include` only ever includes *files*, not also directories - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13524).

You *could* make your command work by (a) switching from `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-Item` and (b) filtering out non-directories after the fact, but that is less efficient than the alternatives above:

```
Get-Item C:\thePath\* -Include p* | Where-Object PSIsContainer
```